# ASP.NET Core - Raw SQL Query without any specific entity/model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am developing an application using ASP.NET Core Web API, where the purpose is to allow it's users to construct SQL Queries in a user friendly manner.

The model to construct the queries works fine, the problem is that the query results may vary a lot, so we can't have a specific model to map those queries to, otherwise EF Core would do the job.

But if a user wants to add a new column to the query the result set changes and there wouldn't be any property to map to.

Is it even possible to develop such an application using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: You can use GetSchema to get the tables and column from the database.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?force_isolation=true&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: A [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0) may be a simple solution.

Comment: Just use `SqlDataReader` instead. Columns can be variable. Also hella lot faster than EF.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Entity Framework isn't the only data access method in .NET, and relies heavily on ADO.NET.

Comment: You should probably familiarize yourself with ADO.NET ([System.Data namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data?view=net-6.0)) since you'll need to work with the DB at that level rather than utilizing an ORM. Particular types would be DataTable and IDataReader. [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/introduction-microsoft-data-sqlclient-namespace?view=sql-server-ver16) builds on top of ADO.NET to provide the main way of accessing MS SQL Server in .NET.

Comment: IMO, number of columns is nowhere near as big a concern as users requesting millions of rows. Make sure you limit the rowcount.